# Properly vertically centering links and images

Tags: html, css, image, drop-down-menu

I have a completely CSS drop down menu. The problem I am having is that the image in the link and the text are not vertically aligning the way I want.

[image: Problem]

I don't want the bottom of the text and the bottom of the image to line up. I want the their centers to line up, more like this:

[image]

Here is how I create the menu:

```
<li><a class="head" href="#">Link 1 &nbsp;&nbsp; &blacktriangledown; </a>
<ul>
<li><a class="sub" href="#">Monkey 1 <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"></a></li>
<li><a class="sub" href="#">Monkey 2 <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"></a></li>
<li><a class="sub" href="#">Monkey 3 <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"></a></li>
<li><a class="sub" href="#">Monkey 4 <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"></a></li>
<li><a class="sub" href="#">Monkey 5 <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

And here is what I tried to fix the problem but it failed:

```
ul li{
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the height of each list (`li`) element? Using this value place the css value,

`line-height: {value here}`

Also placing this on your img would be likely result in the best case scenario. If you could link to the site I can probably give you better instructions.

Comment: This, and make your image a background-image of your li's. Use CSS background options to center them.

Comment: Here is a link http://overactiverexburg.com/Sage/index.php I'll try the line height

Comment: The line height doesn't work, I suspect it's because it's not a block, a quick 'hacky' way to fix it would be to apply a `paddin-top:10px` to the img css

Comment: Regardless of the value I enter for the line-height: the result is the same (except the links get real tall sometimes)

Comment: what do you mean placing this on the image?

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was add this line to the style of the image

```
vertical-align:middle;
```